# An Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: react-native

It was working few days ago. I did not update anything. 
Removed node_modules folder - same thing.

What might went wrong? Please point to it.

already tried to add to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
- tools:node="replace"
or
- tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
  android:appComponentFactory="whatever"
```

Nothing helped.

build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
    }
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Here is an error from console

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
...\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade the react-native-device-info will also work 
`yarn upgrade react-native-device-info@2.1.2`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Run it - did not help. I don't use this library, so maybe you have another ideas?

Comment: Hi Andrey,
Try including the libraries forcefully. To do that copy these lines in the following location. android->app->build.gradel. 
The lines are as follows: 
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0' force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0' force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9' force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0' } }

Comment: @Andriy - This is just a temporary fix. Check which library is not working and try to degrade it's version. Moreover i have answered the answer separetely, Mark that as answered instead of this to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Try including the libraries forcefully.
To do that copy these lines in the following location: `android->app->build.gradel`.
The lines are as follows:

```
configurations.all { 
  resolutionStrategy { 
    force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0' 
    force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0' 
    force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9' 
    force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0' 
  }
}
```

This is just a temprory fix.